# Python: how to compute the sum of a variabel in a netCDF file in a radius of n closest pixels?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, netcdf

I have a netCDF that looks like the following ad is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qTkAtwoXdZISKU_9h-1RtSxuwFn3JVoD/view?usp=sharing):

```
import xarray as xr
ds=xr.open_dataset('merged_new.nc')
ds
```

[image]

The dataset has a spatial resolution of `300m`. The variable `Forest` is a binary variable `0` or `1`.

For each pixel (point) I would like to count the sum of `Forest` in a radius of `30km` (i.e. ~300 closest pixels). I would like to do a sort of moving windows that allow me to assign to each pixel the sum of `Forest` in a radius of `30km`.

Ideally I would like to add a variable to the dataset called `ForestSum` that is the sum of `Forest` in the surrounding.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to convert Forest, Lat, Lon to Pandas dataframe? (or numpy array)

Comment: yes sure. Converting to a Pandas dataframe would be to much time consuming however.

Comment: I know how to find all points inside a radius but I need to extract each coordinates of Forest :) And I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Corralien we can extract the values in this way, `forest=ds['Forest'].values`,  `latitutde=ds['lat'].values`, `longitude=ds['lon'].values`

Comment: You have too many records in your dataset!!!. I will post my method but it's unusable :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `BallTree` from `sklearn`:

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric

ds = xr.open_dataset('merged_new.nc')

forest = ds['Forest'].values
latitude = ds['lat'].values
longitude = ds['lon'].values

df = pd.DataFrame(forest, latitude, longitude).rename_axis(index='lat', columns='lon') \
                                              .stack().rename('forest').reset_index()

# Prepare data
coords = np.radians(df[['lat', 'lon']])
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
tree = BallTree(coords, metric=dist)
```

Now you can query data. Suppose for the first point

```
# lat: -7.1125, lon: -73.9875
>>> df.iloc[tree.query_radius([coords.iloc[0]], r=0.003)[0]]['forest'].sum()
3080
```

In theory, you can do but the process is killed because there are too many records:

```
indices = tree.query_radius(coords, r=0.003)
df['sum'] = [df.iloc[i]['forest'].sum() for i in indices]
```

You can use a multiprocessing version and slice data.

Comment: Did you find a solution?